# Upgrading ruby form 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 cuased server crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

My `rails 3.2.8` application was using `ruby1.8.7` and  was running perfectly. Recently, i've upgraded `ruby` version to `1.9.3`, which caused server to crash. I updated all gems to be compatible with ruby's latest version. But since then, apache is not running my application. If I run rails webrick server, site is accessible using IP address and port. But it is not accessible using domain's name as Apache's configuration doesn't seem to be correct. It was quite fine earlier, I didn't change it or something. I just upgraded Ruby. Anyone got any idea what I'm missing here? Please help.

apache configurations files are as follow.

**apache2.conf**

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers          5
  MinSpareServers       5
  MaxSpareServers      10
  MaxClients          150
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
  StartServers          2
  MinSpareThreads      25
  MaxSpareThreads      75 
  ThreadLimit          64
  ThreadsPerChild      25
  MaxClients          150
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
  StartServers          2
  MinSpareThreads      25
  MaxSpareThreads      75 
  ThreadLimit          64
  ThreadsPerChild      25
  MaxClients          150
  MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r..
```

**test.myapplication.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName test.myapplication.com

  ServerAlias XX.XX.XX.X/mytest

  DocumentRoot /home/XXXX/public_html/public 

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/XXXXX_errors.log

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/XXXXX_access.log combined

  SetEnv RAILS_ENV production

  <Directory /home/XXXXX/public_html/public>

    Allow from all

    Options -MultiViews

  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you show us your ruby app log so we can see what causes the crash ?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in `production log`

Comment: And in your apache log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to update the apache configuration to use new ruby.

So in your apache conf you should have something like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2@rails3/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.2/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.2
```

You should just need to fix the paths..